# How to pass values or data between two function with parameters in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, delegates

I have been trying to pass lat and long from one function to another function but i am unable to do that...i have tried doing it using declaring a variables inside my class but the value it is returning after print is nil. i have used delegation to fetch lat and long from another viewcontroller

Both the functions are under same class

i want to pass it inside latt and longg so that i can decode it

```
@IBAction func locatioButtonTapped(_ sender : Any) {

        self.fetch(latt: //latitude*, longg: //longitude*)

    }
```

This is the delegate function that is fetching lat and long from the actual source function

```
extension MapViewController : LatLongDelegate {
    func latlong(lat: Double, long: Double) {

        let latt = lat
        let long = long

    }
```

i want to get the value from lat and long to *latitude* & *longitude*..i am new to swift..pls help

Comment: what are those * within the first function?! you can read about functions here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_functions.htm

Comment: You can wrap long and lat in a `CLLocation` and pass that around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't understand properly your problem. But as i understand that you can use this.

```
func firstFunc(lat: Double, long: Double) {
   //do something
   secondFunc(lat: lat, long: long)
}

func secondFunc(lat: Double, long: Double) {
   //do something
}
```

But if you want to use values after process from secondFunc you can use inout parameters.

```
func firstFunc(lat: Double, long: Double) {
   //do something
   var newLat = lat
   var newLong = long
   secondFunc(lat: &newLat, long: &newLong)
   //new values for newLat and newLong after secondFunc
}

func secondFunc(lat: inout Double, long: inout Double) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: ok...what if i need to use that var newlat and var newlong from firstFunc() to an ibAction button so that i can trigger the fetching of data from another function??

Answer (score 0):

You can save lat long values to global variable and access it anywhere.

Comment: Yeah buddy i tried that but some how it is returning nil value...